# The method getExpressionFactory() from the type Application refers to the missing type ExpressionFactory

Tags: maven, jsf-2

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 application and I'm trying to programmatically adding an ajax action to a programmatically created UIComponent (the equivalent of statically declared f:ajax listener in a commandLink) as shown in [this blog](http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/jee/71-programatically-adding-ajax-actions-to-uicomponents).

When I tried to get an ExpressionFactory in order to create a MethodExpression, this way:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application application = fc.getApplication();
ExpressionFactory ef = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
```

So, just when I wrote these lines, I got an error saying:

```
The method getExpressionFactory() from the type Application refers to the missing type ExpressionFactory.
```

The only available quick fix was to configure the build path.

I don't know what exactly I should do, am I missing any JAR to resolve this problem?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>esprit.pfe2013</groupId>
  <artifactId>GCFTest4addUIC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GestionCongesFeki Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>       
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

<!--   <repositories> -->
<!-- <repository> -->
<!--            <id>central</id> -->
<!--            <name>Central Repository</name> -->
<!--            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url> -->
<!--            <layout>default</layout> -->
<!--            <snapshots> -->
<!--                <enabled>false</enabled> -->
<!--            </snapshots> -->
<!--        </repository> -->


<!--    </repositories> -->

    <dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>        
</dependency>


        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSF 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>






    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <finalName>GCFTest4addUIC</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>





</project>
```

Comment: @BalusC : "Not a JSF problem. Just a build tool problem. Further fixed poor attention to the Shift key." --> what does't it means ?!

Comment: I will pay attention for this in the future , i promise !!

Comment: This helped me http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-el-expressionfactory/. i resolved this problem by adding this dependancy : <dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
 <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>